# How to Handle Timezone Conversion for Timestamps from QuestDB in JavaScript (React)?

Tags: javascript, timezone, questdb

I'm working with QuestDB in a JavaScript (React) environment and facing an issue with
timestamp values. When the client's browser reads these timestamp values, they are
automatically converted to the browser's local timezone. This is problematic, especially
when dealing with timestamps around midnight, as they can jump to the previous day due
to the timezone shift.

For example, if each timestamp value represents `00:00:00 UTC`, but the browser is in CET
(Central European Time), the time shown is one hour less instead of one hour more,
despite the fact that CET = UTC+1. This behavior is not what we want, as our QuestDB
server is set to UTC.

How can we avoid this automatic timezone conversion in the browser to ensure that the
timestamps are displayed correctly?

Comment: If you are not getting the behavior you desire with some code you wrote, then you need to _show_ that code in your question - not just state the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: edited after receiving a comment. Thanks!*

When dealing with timestamps from QuestDB in a JavaScript environment, it's important
to remember that timestamps are in UTC, but the browser will interpret them in the local
timezone. This is really not related to QuestDB, but since QuestDB is a time-series database this might happen often when using JS.

For more context and to avoid some common errors, please do check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).

Here are a couple of solutions you might want to try:

1. **Using `toISOString()` for UTC Representation:**
   If you're rendering the Date object, it will display in the local timezone by default.
   To get a UTC timestamp representation, use `toISOString()`:

   ```js
   const date = new Date(1704974700000);
   console.log(date.toISOString()); // Converts to a string representing the UTC timestamp
   ```
2. **Using `toUTCString()` for a Human-Readable String:**
   For a more human-readable UTC string, `toUTCString()` can be used:

   ```js
   const date = new Date(1704974700000);
   console.log(date.toUTCString());
   ```

These methods allow you to control how timestamp values from QuestDB are displayed in
the browser, ensuring accuracy regardless of the client's local timezone.

Comment: 1) Did ChatGPT write this?  It reads like it did.  2) The first two approaches demonstrate an anti-pattern known as "epoch shifting".  You should _not_ use them.  See the subsection "Common Errors" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).  3) Nothing here is specific to QuestDB or React.  It's just how the JS `Date` object works.

Comment: Thanks! This was actually asked on questdb slack user group by a real user and replied by another one. I thought it would be useful so I posted it here :)

Comment: I edited my original reply, linking to the other answer and removing the incorrect options. Thank you @MattJohnson-Pint!

Comment: Yep, lots of people make the epoch shifting mistake.  Sometimes it works for them, in a narrow focus sort of way, on a particular use case.  Or they just don't notice the times where it doesn't work correctly (such as near DST transitions).  Eventually they run into problems and fix it, but it's too late - they've already told everyone else how great their solution was, and the problem cascades like a virus.  The same thing has happened with the "always use UTC" misadvice.